# Remembering variables after game has ended in XNA c#

Tags: c#, xml, xna-4.0

I just made a game that you get coins in. The problem is, every time you quit and play again later, this number resets. I was wondering how I could store this variable. If anyone knows the answer, please explain it very simply, because I have not tried anything like this before.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the value(s) to a local file, one way is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203924.aspx

Comment: thank you but as I said in the post i need a little bit more help than this.

Comment: If you go through all the steps in that link you should be able to do what you are asking. What more do you need help on?

Comment: and where does this save the file too?

Comment: In the example just to the root in a file named "savegame.sav". Halfway down the page shows how to read the file too. It does seem like a lot of code for the task, but it's worth following the steps.